# Wordpress on EC2 is slow

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've installed my 3rd wordpress site on m1.small instance (LAMP) and it became unusable slow. I assume I am pushing the limits, I checked CPU and it went from 10% to 25-30%. Besides that I can't figure out what exactly made it slow. Other two wordpress sites perform on the same high speed (they are all on the same instance, pointing to the same database). Are there any tools I could measure and figure why simple wordpress site takes a while to load?

Comment: You might get more answers on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ although I wouldn't jump to the conclusion of saying that's the best place for it, since profiling is more of a server administration activity.

Comment: thanks, I just posted it on serverfault and going to close this one.